# Question on Filippov regularization (for ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$f'(t)=1-2\ \text{sgn}(f(t))=\begin{cases}3&f(t)<0\\ 1&f(t)=0\\-1&f(t)>0\end{cases},$$
with initial condition $f(0)=f_0\neq 0$.

- In my lecture, it's written that : each solution reach $0$ in finite time. If the solution reaches $0$, it cannot leave, because $\dot f>0$ if $f<0$ and $\dot f<0$ if $f>0$. The solution will therefore stay at $f=0$, which implies $\dot f(t)=0$ when $f(t)=0$. Note that $f(t)=0$ with $\dot f(t)=0$ is not a solution in the classic sense since $0\neq 1-2\ \text{sgn}(0)$.

For this reason, we consider $F(x)=\{f(x)\}$ if $f$ is continuous at $x$, and if not, we consider $F(x)=ConvexHull\{3,-1\}=[-1,3]$. We therefore consider the system $$\begin{cases}
\dot f(t)\in F(x(t)),\\ f(0)=f_0\neq 0.\end{cases}$$

**Question** Can someone explain me why we do that ? It looks to come from nowhere, and I don't see the interest.

In somehow, I imagine that as far it reach $0$, the particle bounce at $0$, and goes up with speed one, and as far as it leaves $0$, it immediately goes back to $0$ with speed $1$. But it looks difficult to put this mathematically. Is this a good interpretation ?

Comment: What about your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3298459/115115) on this topic? I went back and highlighted the motivational paragraph in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your bouncing idea does not work, as that gives no convergent scheme when increasing the time resolution. In a strong sense, the ODE solution ends at the discontinuity (the domain of any ODE is an open set where the right side is continuous), and by the shape of the vector field on both sides of it, there is no continuation (to the other side) possible.

---

In the standard ODE theory a function $f$ is assumed continuous on its domain $D\subset\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n$. Then the existence theorems tell us that an initial value problem $\dot x=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$ for some IC $(t_0,x_0)\in D$ has a local solution which can be extended as maximal solution to the boundary of $D$ (more specifically, to leave any compact set inside $D$).

Here now functions $f$ are considered that are piecewise continuous, that is, there is a decomposition of $D$ into disjoint open sets $D_k$ so that $\bar D=\bigcup D_k$ and $f$ is continuous on each of the $D_k$. Now one can ask if there exists a function $x$ which is piecewise continuous on segments $(t_k,t_{k+1})$, where restricted to such a segment it is a maximal ODE solution of $f$ restricted to $D_k$.

This can fail as in the example in question. There are points on common "inner" boundary segments of the $D_k$ where each partial ODE only has solutions ending in that point, none leaving that point. There is no way to continue a solution from this inner point of $D$.

In all practical applications, seeing the restrictions floating point numerics or the quantum nature of physical reality, a jump is indistinguishable from a very steep ramp. So one idea is to replace the jump with a not so steep ramp to get a numerically viable continuous function on the whole of $D$ and then compare the results for different degrees of "steepness".

---

As the differential equation with discontinuous or stronger singular right side is some generalized version of the continuous ODE, one can use the same tools one uses for generalized functions. One can consider sequences of continuous functions that converge almost anywhere to the given function (or in some stronger topology as necessary to completely characterize the right side). One can select those functions so that the difference to the given function is restricted to a very small neighborhood of the discontinuity. Then in that neighborhood, by the *intermediate value theorem*, all values inside the convex hull (of some close neighbors) of the limit values are taken by the continuous approximation.

Now one can try to eliminate the approximation process and just consider the set valued version $\dot x\in F(x)$ from the start. This now is only a characterization of a generalized solution, no recipe to compute it numerically. Also, some branching is now possible, it is not deterministic on when a solution must leave the sliding mode, and there may be multiple directions to do so. For instance, in the modified example $\dot x=f(t,x)=1+(t-2){\rm sign}(x)$ the singular point $x=0$ changes from absorbing to repelling at $t=2$. However, valid generalized solutions can branch of at any time after that and in both directions.

Comment: I try to illustrate your second paragraph. So, I consider (to make easier) $\dot f(t)=-sgn(f_t)$ with $f^0\neq 0$. I take a sequence of continuous function s.t. $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ where $f(x)=f^0-t$ if $t<f^0$ and $f^0>0$ and $f(x)= t+f^0$ if $f^0<0$ and $t<-f^0$. So, I select $f_n$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon $ when $x$ is close enough from $0$. And you say that the derivative of $f_n$ will be in the convex Hull $co\{-1,1\}=[-1,1]$ ? Since this is not true, I imagine you have something else in mind...

Comment: At the end, since will never use the fact that $\dot f(t)=0$ when $f(t)=0$, why should we consider this ? (because we take $\dot f(t)\in [-1,1]$).

Comment: There is a notation inconsistence in naming the right side of the ODE and the solution function. My answers are for $\dot x(t)=f(t,x(t))$, in the example $f(t,x)=-{\rm sign}(x)$.

Comment: So, just to conclude, if I proceed as your previous post (in my other question). I take $h_{a,b}(x)=\frac{4x-3a-b}{b-a}$ if $a\leq x\leq b$, $h_{a,b}(x)=3$ if $x<a$ and $h_{a,b}(x)=-1$ if $x\geq b$. Then, the solution (that start at $x_0>b>0$) is $$x_{a,b}(t)=x_0-t$$ if $t<x_0-b$ and $$x_{a,b}(t)=\frac{3a+b}{4}+(x_0-\frac{3a+b}{4})e^{-\frac{4}{b-a}t}$$ when $t\geq x_0-b$. So, when $(a,b)\to (0,0)$, then $x(t)=\lim_{(a,b)\to 0}x_{a,b}(t)=\max(0,x_0-t)$. Moreover, $\dot x_{a,b}(0)=1$ for all $a,b$, so $\dot x(0):=\lim_{(a,b)\to 0}\dot x_{a,b}(0)=1$. Does this work ?

Comment: I would formulate it as $\dot x=1-2h_{a,b}(x)$ where $h_{a,b}$ is the sign approximation. This gives $1-2\frac{2x-a-b}{b-a}=\frac{3b+a-4x}{b-a}$ for the middle segment, having the right boundaries for a continuous continuation to the outer segments. So for $x_0>0$ indeed $x(t)=x_0-t$ for $t\le x_0-b$, then $$x_{a,b}(t)=\frac{a+3b}{4}+(x_0-\frac{a+3b}{4})e^{-\frac{4}{b-a}t}.$$ Then by all formulas $\dot x_{a,b}(0)=-1$, if $b<x_0$, which is consistent with the original equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (indeed, I made a mistake in the sign of $h_{a,b}$, but anyway). So at the end, what is $x(t)$ ? Isn't isn't it $x(t)=\max(0,x_0-t)$ ? (and thus, $x$ get stuck at $0$). No ?

Comment: Yes, that remains unchanged.