# A simple ODE with sign nonlinearity on the RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose we have the following ODE:
$$
x'(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x(t) < 0 \\
-1  & \text{if } x(t) \ge 0
\end{cases}
\qquad
x(0) = 0.
$$
I am not sure whether the solution exists in the usual sense.

I think the following should hold in some weak sense. 
Since $x'(0) = -1$, $x$ should decrease so that there exists $1 \gg \epsilon > 0$ such that 
$x(t) < 0$ for all $t \in (0, \epsilon)$.
However, as soon as $x(t) < 0$, since $x'(t) = 1$, $x(t)$ should increase. 
Thus, it intuitively makes sense to conclude $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

However, I am not sure what do show this or even how to define the solution in this case.

Any answers/suggestions/comments will be very appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3298459/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3381690/115115 for a discussion on how that connects to Filippov's theory of generalized ODE and sliding mode. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767096/3088138, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60309851/3088138 on how to handle such a "sliding" or "bouncing" region numerically without repeatedly confusing the solver with the singularities of the jumps.

Comment: Such ODEs are of interest in control theory, namely, in hybrid dynamical systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is good. However, to properly answer your question, I suggest you look at the theorem for the existence of a solution to an IVP in the "classical" sense.

This is straight out of *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Richard K. Miller and Anthony N. Michel, page 47:

**Theorem 2.3**: If $f \in C(D)$ and $(\tau,\xi)\in D$, then the IVP has a solution defined on $|t-\tau| \leq c.$

The IVP is:

\begin{cases} x'=f(t,x) \\ x(\tau)=\xi \end{cases}

Note that $D \subset \mathbb{R_{+}\times \mathbb{R}^n}$ is a **domain**, that is $D$ is an open, connected (and nonempty) set in $(t,x)$ coordinates.

The function you are given in the right hand side is discontinuous, so a solution in this sense may or may not exist. Therefore, the theory you learn about ODEs in undergraduate does not really apply here.

However, it is possible to talk about solutions in the sense of Filippov. Since this is a whole discipline by itself (and I don't think I can cover everything in one post), I will simply refer you to look at the following:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3583.pdf

See in particular, pages (in document) 8, 13, and 14, which cover the same IVP you give.

I should also mention that the term *weak solutions* (i.e. using Sobolev Spaces) is used exclusively in BVPs/PDEs, and that it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the notion of the solution I am looking for!