# How to get a Filippov solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, piecewise-continuity, nonlinear-dynamics, singular-solution

Recently, I read a book ISSN 2195-9862 about the Filippov theory. There is a differential inclusion
$$\dot{x}\in F(x)=\begin{cases}
-1&x>0\\
[-1,1]&x=0\\
1&x<0
\end{cases}\\
x(t_0)=x_0$$
For this differential inclusion, the authors write that "The Filippov solution is
$$x(t)=\begin{cases}
x(0)-sgn(x_0)t,\ t\in [0,|x(0)|]\\
0, t\geq |x(0)|
\end{cases}\\$$
where $sgn(x)$ is the single-valued mapping and $sgn(0)=0$."

My question is  how to get this "Filippov solution"? I can follow the part $x(0)-sgn(x_0)t,\ t\in [0,|x(0)|]$. But why $x(t)=0$ for $t\geq |x(0)|$? I cannot figure out what happen at $x=0$.

Comment: What is the value of the state when $t=|x(0)|$? What happens next?

Comment: In an introduction to ODE one learns to find a solution by construction it, by transforming the DE until a direct integration is possible. It is a rare set of examples where this works. In general, finding a solution is a selection process, from all $C^1$ functions select the ones where the equation is satisfied over some interval. // Here look up "sliding mode solutions" and see the [previous question to the same task](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298459/sliding-motion-and-fillippov-system)